# any online sfx library that has the exact (the same) files that are sold on cd's?

Tags: sound-libraries

Hello, I am looking for a online database of sound effects that has the same audio files that you can find on commercial cd's so i can buy separately just the sound i need. I've heard some sounds that would be perfect for a project at my friend's studio but don't want to buy whole collection. The example would be Hollywood Edge Foley series. Are there any 1:1 online copies of cd's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also sonomic.com

Comment: this looks good! already found some hollywood edge samples! Will check some more but positive for now! thanks Morten!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any that do specifically what you are looking for.

You could try contacting those libraries to see if they will sell you just the specific sounds you are looking for, but there are a bunch of online resources that sell individual sound files you can purchase. Sounddogs.com is one of the best resources in that respect.

Comment: +1 Sounddogs.com is the place to go when you've searched your library for an hour and can't find that exact wind you want or the squeeky hinge you need that puts the cherry on top of your design.

Answer (score 1):

Sounddogs.com has all the Sound Ideas and Soundstorm stuff.  Not sure if any site has HW Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Gamecues seems to be a pretty good place to start. It offers many sound effects from the Sound Ideas collections, BlastwaveFX, and others.  There's an integrated search engine on the website which I believe allows you to sort by author/publisher.  I'm not sure if the have any Hollywood Edge sounds though.  http://www.gamecues.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.audiomicro.com.  They have a lot of Hollywood Edge sounds available individually.  You might need to do an advanced search and narrow the results to the artist "hollywoodedge" to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SFXSource.com has the BBC libraries.